# Which Fragment lifecycle methods we should commit FragmentTrasaction to avoid famous java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: android, android-fragments

I was wondering, what is the `Fragment` lifecycle methods, I should commit `FragmentTransaction` to avoid famous

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

According to http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html, it gives great tip, on how to avoid such exception, by commit `FragmentTransaction`

### FragmentActivity

- onCreate()
- onResumeFragments()
- onPostResume()

---

### Fragment

- ???

However, how about `Fragment`? What is the suitable `Fragment` lifecycle we should commit our fragment? For instance, under very rare situation, I will get exception from Google Play Console crash report, while trying to commit `Fragment` in another `Fragment`'s `onCreate`.

```
public class BuyPortfolioFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final FragmentManager fm = this.getFragmentManager();
        // Check to see if we have retained the worker fragment.
        this.statusBarUpdaterFragment = (StatusBarUpdaterFragment)fm.findFragmentByTag(STATUS_BAR_UPDATER_FRAGMENT);

        if (this.statusBarUpdaterFragment == null) {
            this.statusBarUpdaterFragment = StatusBarUpdaterFragment.newInstance();
            this.statusBarUpdaterFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
            // java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
            fm.beginTransaction().add(statusBarUpdaterFragment, STATUS_BAR_UPDATER_FRAGMENT).commit();
        } else {
            statusBarUpdaterFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
        }
```

p/s I know I can avoid such exception by using `commitAllowingStateLoss`. I want to use it as last resource.

Comment: i normally commit fragment transactions from Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Fragment's lifecycle state not always matches Activity's. Fragment's method `getFragmentManager()` returns the `FragmentManager` of it's hosting `Activity` (unless it's a child Fragment, if so this method returns the child fragment manager of a hosting Fragment). You may never know in which state is Fragment's hosting Activity unless you make tracking code. So it's really possible that the transaction eventually may be committed after Activity `onSaveInstanceState()` was called.

I suggest using `getChildFragmentManager()` and deal with child fragments from fragments.

Or if your intention was really to control Activity Fragments, make accessors for controlling it's state, like

```
// Activity method
public void showSomeFragment() {
    if (mFragmentTransactionsAllowed) {
        // do transaction
    }
}

// And track the boolean

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
    // override on onCreate() in case if Activity object is reused and state was true
    mFragmentTransactionsAllowed = true;
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // override here so that if activity goes foreground but not yet destroyed
    mFragmentTransactionsAllowed = true; 
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mFragmentTransactionsAllowed = true;
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mFragmentTransactionsAllowed = false;
}
```